# Clarification on how to define a class

Tags: oop, python

What does doing the following mean, I've been seeing it around online a lot and don't understand why the word object is written

```
  class Solution(object):
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's called 'Inheritance'.
You can read more in section 9.5 here.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

class likes a blueprint. as an example you can consider a registration form, this form is a class and if you fill up a copy of this form it will be an object.in a class we have some variables are called attribute or field and we got some functions that each of them is called method. if you allocate some space of your memory to an unit which has value for all attributes of your class, this is your object.